# Add a index on a field in Cloud Datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-search-api

I want to add an index on my field `DateTimeProperty` in Cloud Datastore.

I have created a class like the following:

```
class Activity(BaseModel):
    activity = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    last_updated_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Now I want to run a query against it, like this:

```
txt = u'last_updated_date >= {}'.format(last_login_date)
query = search.Query(query_string=txt)
result = search_index.search(query)
```

I have created a index on the property `last_update_date`, however, it will search only on date field not the time field.

So, if I create any new activity today before `sysdate`, it will still show in the query...

Comment: What do you mean "it will search only on date field not the time field"?  Also, can you edit the question? I can't understand what is the issue right now.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use the [GAE Python Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/) (which your query snippet is using) to query the datastore (using the `ndb` client library) - that won't work - the search API doesn't use the datastore. From that link (emphasis mine):

> Documents and indexes are saved **in a separate persistent store**
>   optimized for search operations. The Search API can index any number
>   of documents. **The App Engine Datastore may be more appropriate for
>   applications that need to retrieve very large result sets**.

To query the datastore you need to use the [NDB Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries) and [Datastore Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes) (different that the search API indexes).

If you really want to use the search API then you need to create corresponding search API documents from your info using the same API (instead of storing the info in the datastore).

Comment: I have used search_api to create index
    search.DateField(name='last_updated_date', value=instance.last_updated_date)